# program evaluating occurrences of repeated words

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
vector<string> Letter;
float frequency1(string word)
{
   float count=0.0;
   for (int i=0;i<Letter.size();++i)
   {
      transform(word.begin(),word.end(),word.begin(),::tolower);
      transform(Letter[i].begin(),Letter[i].end(),Letter[i].begin(),::tolower);   

      if (strcmp(word.c_str(),Letter[i].c_str())==0)
      {
          count+=1;
      }   
  }
  count=(count/Letter.size())*100;
  if (count>=0.5)
  {
         return count;
  }
  else
  {
      return 0.0;
  }
}                                       

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("frequent.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Error opening file!"<<endl;
    }

    while(!fin.eof()) 
    {
        string buffer;              
        getline(fin,buffer,' ');
        cout<<buffer<<endl;
        Letter.push_back(buffer);
    }
    cout<<endl;
    vector<string> frequent;
    vector<float> frequency;
    for (int i=0;i<Letter.size();++i)
    {
        string a=Letter[i];
        int k=0;
        for (int j=0;j<i;++j)
        {
            transform(a.begin(),a.end(),a.begin(),::tolower);
            transform(Letter[j].begin(),Letter[j].end(),Letter[j].begin(),::tolower);
            if (a==Letter[j])
            {
                 break;
            }
            k++;
        }
        int size=Letter.size();
        if (k!=size-1)
        {
            continue;
        }            
        float counter=frequency1(a);
        if(counter>0.0)
        {
            frequent.push_back(Letter[i]);
            frequency.push_back(counter);
        }
    }
    cout<<"Here are the repeated words"<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<frequency.size();++i)
    {
        cout<<"       "<<frequent[i]<<", frequency: "<<frequency[i]<<endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I am writing a program which determines the frequency of the repeated words in a document(text). If frequency is greater or equal to 0.5, the word passes as a repeated words. but when I run it, it doesn't show me any repeated word although I even calculated manually and know that there are repeated words in the document. I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: `count=(count/Letter.size())*100;` what is this line doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should `exit` or wrap the remainder of `main` into an else, when you cannot open your input file

```
if (fin.fail())
{
    cout<<"Error opening file!"<<endl;
}
```

Otherwise, you'd go on and try to read from an invalid stream.

You read your words with [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) and a blank `' '` as delimiter. This means, that you include newlines `'\n'`, tabs `'\t'`, etc. in your words, which might not be what you intended. A better, and safer, approach to read your words, would be

```
std::string word;
while (fin >> word) {
    // process word
}
```

This skips *all* whitespace and detects EOF properly as an added benefit.

There might be further problems as well.